# Regarding proof of Bolzano's theorem (Csez Kosniowski)

Tags: calculus, general-topology, continuity

I am trying to understand the lemma 10.1 (IVT) of "A first course in Algebraic topology" by C. Kosniowski.

The lemma states,

If $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous with $f(0)f(1) \leq0$, then $\exists \hspace{2mm} t\in I: f(t)=0$.

The proof assumes $f(t)\not=0, \hspace{2mm}\forall t\in I\hspace{2mm}$  for a contradiction.
Then constructs $g:I \rightarrow S^0$ as $g(t)=f(t)/\vert f(t) \vert$.

Apparently, $g$ is to be continuous because $f(0)f(1)<0$, but I don't know why that the strict negativeness of $f(0)f(1)$ assures continuity of $g$. Once I know that $g$ is continuous, then I am done.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is $I=[0,1]$ and $R=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @closedrhombus yes, I wrote R wrong, sorry.

Comment: HINT: The case $f(0)f(1)<0$ implies either $f(1)<0<f(0)$  or $f(0)<0<f(1)$. Both cases can be concluded with the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is continuous and never $0$ then $h(x)=1/f(x)$ is continuous so $j(x)=|h(x)|$is continuous so $g(x)=f(x)j(x)$ is continuous.

Suppose $f(t)$ is never $0.$ Then $g(t)\in \{-1,+1\}$ for every $t\in [0,1].$ But a continuous $g:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ cannot take both values $-1$ and $+1$ without taking every value in between, so $g$ must be constantly $+1$ or constantly $-1.$ But this implies $$[\forall t\in [0,1]\,(f(t)>0)]\;\lor \;[\forall t\in [0,1]\,(f(t)<0)]$$ contrary to $f(0)f(1)\le 0.$

I think it is easier to say that

$(i).$ If $f(0)f(1)=0$ then $0\in \{f(0),f(1)\}\subset \{f(t):t\in [0,1]\}$.

$(ii).$ If $f(0)f(1)<0$ then $\min (f(0),f(1))<0<\max (f(0),f(1))$ implying $$0\in [ \min (f(0),f(1)), \max (f(0),f(1))]\subset \{f(t): t\in [0,1]\}.$$

Comment: I guess I read the proof in the textbook in a  wrong way. I think the strict negativeness of $f(0)f(1)$ was used for surjectivity of $g(t)$ instead of its continuity. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that $I=[0,1]$ and $R=\mathbb{R}$. We know that $f$ is continuous and that $f(t)\neq0$ for all $t\in I$. Then, the function $h: I\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(t)=\frac{1}{|f(t)|}$ is continuous, because the absolute value function is continuous. Because of this, $g=f\cdot h$ is continuous.

A simpler argument is the following:
We say that a set $A\subseteq I$ is connected if and only if it has no non-trivial clopen sets. According to this definition, $I$ is connected. Since $I$ is connected and $f$ is continuous, then $f(I)$ is connected (because if $f(I)$ had a non-trivial clopen set $C$, then $f^{-1}(C)$ would be a non-trivial clopen set of $I$). We're assuming that $f(0)f(1)<0$ and that $f(t)\neq0$ for all $t\in I$. Can you show that this contradicts that $f(I)$ is connected?